# MySQL INSERT INTO using the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, opencart

I'm trying to read all the SKU numbers from my product table and add those as tags into my product description table.

Here is the query I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO product_description (tag)
SELECT sku
FROM product p
WHERE p.product_id = pd.product_id; #I don't know where to define pd
```

Neither of these work:

```
INSERT INTO product_description pd (tag)

INSERT INTO product_description (tag) pd
```

I'm having difficulty figuring out how the `WHERE` clause should be constructed. I need to make sure the product IDs match from both tables and I can't give the first table an alias either.

To clarify my question, I'm actually trying to update my existing data in the product_description table, I'm not trying to add/insert new rows.

Comment: Use aliases => http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: @codedrop p and pd are already aliases. The problem comes from the fact that pd doesn't alias anything

Comment: May be you want to update, not insert?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri how would the update query look like? I'm updating an entire table using data from another table.

Comment: I don't believe you can use an alias in an insert, and you shouldn't need to. It sounds like you want an update, as you're trying to manipulate existing rows, not insert new ones.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify what you really want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for an update query here, as you are setting the value in one table based on it's relation to another.

To do this, you can `JOIN` the tables together using the related column, and set the values accordingly:

```
UPDATE product_description pd
JOIN product p ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
SET pd.tag = p.sku;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8876c) example.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri . . . Au contraire.  This is correct syntax.  The other answer is incorrect.

Comment: @McAdam331, I have already corrected. Didn't know that mysql had some different syntax compared to mssql.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri no harm done, wasn't insulted. Just pointing it out so we can all learn together.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO product_description (tag)
(SELECT sku
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to read all the SKU numbers from my product table and add
>   those as tags into my product description table.

I read this as wanting something like this:

```
INSERT INTO product_description (tag)
    SELECT distinct sku
    FROM product p;
```

If you don't want duplicates, then be sure that you have a unique index/constraint on `product_description(tag)`.

You don't give the structure of the table, but you might want the product id along with the tag:

```
INSERT INTO product_description (product_id, tag)
    SELECT product_id, sku
    FROM product p;
```

Comment: To clarify my question, I'm actually trying to update my existing data in the product_description table, I'm not trying to add/insert new rows.